# Android Sqlite order by desc not working correctly

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

I am very new to Android with Sqlite database programming.
I want to order by desc my game score column. Game score columns type is real and when i try to order by gpoint and desc not working correctly. Please give me some advice. Code is below:

```
public List<Score> getAllScores() {
            List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES+" ORDER BY gpoint DESC";

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Score score = new Score();
                    score.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    score.setPoint(cursor.getFloat(1));
                    score.setLetter(cursor.getString(3));
                    score.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
                    scoreList.add(0, score);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            return scoreList;
        }
```

my test insertions are:

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)9.4, "S",formattedDate));        
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)7.5, "S",formattedDate));        
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)6.6, "S",formattedDate));        
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)8.8, "S",formattedDate));        
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)9.7, "S",formattedDate));
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)11.1, "S",formattedDate));
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)2.1, "S",formattedDate));
        db.addScoreToDB(new Score((float)10.1, "S",formattedDate));
```

result is:

12-24 15:52:24.065: D/Insert:(9901): Inserting ..
12-24 15:52:24.290: D/Reading:(9901): Reading all contacts..

Id: 8 ,Score: 10.1 ,Letter: S

Id: 6 ,Score: 11.1 ,Letter: S

Id: 7 ,Score: 2.1 ,Letter: S

Id: 3 ,Score: 6.6 ,Letter: S

Id: 2 ,Score: 7.5 ,Letter: S

Id: 4 ,Score: 8.8 ,Letter: S

Id: 1 ,Score: 9.4 ,Letter: S

Id: 5 ,Score: 9.7 ,Letter: S

i want result: 2.1, 6.6, 7.5..... so on

Comment: Is there any reason you're using rawquery over just a select? And when selecting, normally you'd use getReadableDatabase(). Something like `getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_SCORES, null, null, null, null ,null, "gpoint desc");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> i want result: 2.1, 6.6, 7.5..... so on

That's an ascending order, not descending. Ascending is the default but you can also specify `ORDER BY column ASC`.

```
Id: 8 ,Score: 10.1 ,Letter: S
Id: 6 ,Score: 11.1 ,Letter: S
Id: 7 ,Score: 2.1 ,Letter: S 
Id: 3 ,Score: 6.6 ,Letter: S 
Id: 2 ,Score: 7.5 ,Letter: S 
Id: 4 ,Score: 8.8 ,Letter: S 
Id: 1 ,Score: 9.4 ,Letter: S 
Id: 5 ,Score: 9.7 ,Letter: S
```

This is an ascending order but sorted lexicographically (alphabetically), not numerically. If you want numerical sorting, either set the `gpoint` column type to `REAL` or cast the values to `REAL`:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (... gpoint REAL ...)
```

or

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY CAST(gpoint AS REAL)
```

Comment: SELECT ... ORDER BY CAST(gpoint AS REAL) this is my solution !!! now everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

please change this query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES+" ORDER BY gpoint DESC";
```

convert gpoint on REAL .

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES+" ORDER BY cast(gpoint as REAL) DESC";
```

i hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try it
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
        KEY_BODY, KEY_TIME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_ALARM}, null, null,null,null,KEY_TIME+" DESC");